# Issues writing htaccess rewrite that allows period

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to modify the htaccess of my social network website to allow period (.) and other symbols, just like instagram and twitter. Here is the one I have already.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ shop.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ shop.php?u=$1
```

Anytime a user (with e.g website.com/b.i.scol, as profile link, tries to enter his profile, what we see next is error.)

Comment: What kind of error do you see?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the error is a 404? The character class `[]` of your regex doesn't allow for `.`s, add it in and you should be good to go. Additionally you can use a `?` to make a character/group optional which will cut down the number of expressions you need.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ shop.php?u=$1
```

You also need the `-` to be last (or first) in a character class to be literal, if it is between 2 characters it creates a range.

Also `a-zA-Z0-9_` can be shortened to `\w`. So

```
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ shop.php?u=$1
```

also should work.

Comment: ... upon thinking this over more you should have something unique in the URL, like `/user/` so you aren't redirecting every request without a `/` in it. e.g. this also will redirect `image.jpg`, `test.php`, `style.css`, etc.

Comment: #chris85 I just tried what you told me to do, but didn't work. Please I badly need this to work, but I'm stuck

Comment: Thanks #chris85 the error is page not found, and sometimes the page appears but the contents of the page disappears